# design pattern so that a static init method is always called before a call to static method

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns

I have requirement in which, I have to call some initializing method before the call of any static method in the class.

Now the problem is that whenever i add new static method to that class, I forget to call that initializing method, I was wondering if there any design pattern to solve this problem. I want the initializing method is always called whenever a static method is called from the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AOP might be an overkill for this problem. What you may want to try is to delegate each of the static methods to another class and add the initialization code to the constructor of that class. Something like:

```
class StaticClass {
    public static void m1 () {
      new Worker().m1();
    }
    public static void m2 () {
      new Worker().m2();
    }
}

class Worker {
   public Worker() {
     intialize();
   }
   public void m1() {
     // Real m1 work
   }
   public void m2() {
     // Real m2 work
   }
}
```

This atleast solves the problem of forgetting to put in the call to init code.

That said, this looks like: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Can you step back and tell us why you need this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html) addresses this situation pretty well for Java. It uses [AspectJ annotations](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html) to make things a little simpler, although personally I think AOP is fairly complex.

Answer (score 0):

Java [has static initialization blocks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). Something like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
   static {
      // Your code here
   }
}
```

Comment: Static constructor will be called once, I want to call the method every time when the constructor is called.

Comment: Then probably you want something on the lines of AspectJ (http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), although I don't know if it will work on static methods.